# Stop Django from minifying my less file

Tags: python, django, less

I'm generating a .less file via django's templating. I'm essentially doing this the same way I would with html pages using a base less file...

```
@import: "somefile.less";

// The bg image
body {background-image: url('{% block image %}{% endblock %}');}
```

and another less file to extend it

```
{% extends "baseless/normal.less" %}

{% block image %}trees.jpg{% endblock %}
```

This is actually working fine, except that Django is removing lines from the output. this basically breaks the less file as I have a lot of //comments requiring line breaks.

```
@import: "somefile.less";// The bg image body {background-image: url('{trees.jpg');}
```

Is there a way to prevent it from doing this?

Comment: use `/* The bg image */` instead of `//The bg image`

Comment: Thanks. That would work indeed. However the file is verrry big. I'd be interested in a solution that wouldn't require this change anyway, especially for readability.

Comment: Maybe [this](http://www.caktusgroup.com/blog/2012/03/05/using-less-django/) could be of some help?

Comment: Thanks. That might be nice down the road, but since I'd really like to demonstrate loading Kickstrap client-side for this particular project.

Comment: Are you sure it's Django that is removing the line breaks? Django shouldn't remove white space like that.

Comment: I have a .less file in my templates folder with line breaks and all so it's probably Django.

Comment: are you using pipeline? if so, can you verify the settings? because i have never faced this issue in the past.

Comment: I'm not sure, would that just be called "pipeline" in the INSTALLED_APPS?

Comment: Let me be a little clearer. Django does not remove whitespace out of the box. If the line breaks are being stripped from your template, then there is something in your less template that you haven't shown us (e.g. you're using the spaceless tag), or maybe you're using some middleware or other.

Comment: Apologies if I'm wrong, but I'm pretty sure about this. Unless Djano works differently for Mac/Windows line breaks. Personally, I would love an easy way for Django to remove whitespace, because I find it's not suitable for plain text emails. Hope you find your answer.

Comment: I totally understand, @Alasdair. I'm equally surprised. Is there something I could provide here to help investigate? I don't have any tags or extra middleware. The only extra thing I've installed other than my apps themselves is South.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- If you render this in a shell, it remove lines? If yes, are you using spaceless tag?
- When you render it in browser and it does not remove in shell, are you using a middleware which tries to remove blank lines or something like that?

By the way, **use** django-compressor to compile **less** files.

Comment: How would I do this in the shell? It's in my best interests not to compile here because my site will be providing .LESS files directly to users for download on their own projects.

Comment: Use render_to_string to check it.